# Is there a name for this type of problem involving dominos?

Tags: math, multidimensional-array

There's this problem that my professor showed me that I thought was interesting.

The problem is as follows:
If you have a 2^n by 2^n checkerboard and remove one square from it, will you be able to fill it with L-shaped trominos?

The answer to this is yes, the method of which I thought was interesting.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDpYc.png)

In this example, X is the removed square and the numbers represent the shape of the L-shaped trominos. In every possible permutation of checkerboards, there should be a solution to fill up every square with trominos.

Does anyone know if this kind of problem is named in a field of math? I'd love to learn more about these.

I'm also going to attempt to program this, anyone have any ideas that could help?

Comment: I'm not sure the question is a good fit for this site, maybe in [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)? ... but OTOH, I think this would make a very interesting [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) challenge, and the answers there would definitely give you very good ideas on how to program an algorithm for these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a broad family of problems called ***tiling problems*** that ask when, whether, and how to tile different shapes using a fixed collection of figures.

There are other questions about ***figure subdivisions***, where the question is when, whether, or how to subdivide some larger figure apart into smaller figures of various shapes.